# docker ENV override is not wroking

Tags: docker, nginx, environment-variables

i want replace text in docker image 
so i use ENV to replace text

but when i put text in ENV, ENV is not overrided

my dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d", "/var/log/nginx", "/var/www/html"]

ENV PROXY_PASS http://localhost:3000
ENV SERVER_NAME myserver.com
ENV PEM_PATH /etc/nginx/certs/cert.pem
ENV KEY_PATH /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key

WORKDIR /etc/nginx

RUN rm -f sites-enabled/default
ADD ./sites-available/ssl /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl
RUN sed -ri 's@PROXY_PASS@'${PROXY_PASS}'@' sites-available/ssl
RUN sed -ri 's@SERVER_NAME@'${SERVER_NAME}'@' sites-available/ssl
RUN sed -ri 's@PEM_PATH@'${PEM_PATH}'@' sites-available/ssl
RUN sed -ri 's@KEY_PATH@'${KEY_PATH}'@' sites-available/ssl
RUN cp -f sites-available/ssl sites-available/default
#RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl sites-enabled/default

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx"]
```

target file : ssl

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate  PEM_PATH;
        ssl_certificate_key   KEY_PATH;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name SERVER_NAME;

        location / {
                        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                        proxy_pass PROXY_PASS;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

my run exec

```
docker run -d -e "SERVER_NAME=docker.havehad.kr" --name nginx-ssl -p 443:443 --rm nginx-ssl
```

when i run docker image , `SERVER_NAME` in ssl file should be replaced to 'docker.havehad.kr' but it didn't
it still remain 'myserver.com'
I don't know what is the problem
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 different contexts when dealing with a docker image: **build** context (docker build command) and **run** context (docker run command).

From [dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

> The ENV instruction sets the environment variable  to the value . This value will be in the environment for all subsequent instructions in the build stage and can be replaced inline in many as well.
>
> The ARG instruction defines a variable that users can pass at
> build-time to the builder with the docker build command using the
> --build-arg = flag. If a user specifies a build argument that was not defined in the Dockerfile, the build outputs a
> warning.

It seems that you need a way to change variables used in Dockerfile for changing your sed commands. You should use arguments to achieve that, and you can combine them with environment variables to make them available at run time (docker run command)

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d", "/var/log/nginx", "/var/www/html"]

ARG PROXY_PASS=http://localhost:3000
ARG SERVER_NAME=myserver.com
ARG PEM_PATH=/etc/nginx/certs/cert.pem
ARG KEY_PATH=/etc/nginx/certs/cert.key

ENV PROXY_PASS ${PROXY_PASS}
ENV SERVER_NAME ${SERVER_NAME}
ENV PEM_PATH ${PEM_PATH}
ENV KEY_PATH ${KEY_PATH}


WORKDIR /etc/nginx

RUN rm -f sites-enabled/default
ADD ./sites-available/ssl /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl
RUN sed -ri 's@PROXY_PASS@${PROXY_PASS}@' sites-available/ssl
RUN sed -ri 's@SERVER_NAME@${SERVER_NAME}@' sites-available/ssl
RUN sed -ri 's@PEM_PATH@${PEM_PATH}@' sites-available/ssl
RUN sed -ri 's@KEY_PATH@${KEY_PATH}@' sites-available/ssl
RUN cp -f sites-available/ssl sites-available/default
#RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl sites-enabled/default

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx"]
```

And you can change the arguments values when building the image:

```
$ docker build --build-arg SERVER_NAME=docker.havehad.kr .
```

Your `${SERVER_NAME}` argument will be replaced in the Dockerfile instructions (ENV and RUN) with `docker.havehad.kr`.

If you need to change your sed commands at run-time (docker run), put them into a shell script and use it as ENTRYPOINT